# How to disable admin port in weblogic without weblogic console?

Tags: console, weblogic

I enabled 'admin port' on weblogic and configured Two-Way SSL to 'Client Certs Requested And Enforced' and now I can't have access to weblogic console through admin port, I wanna use normal port by 7001 but I can't:

> Console/Management requests or requests with  specified to 'true' can only be made through an administration channel

How can I disable admin port through WLST or config file?

Comment: When admin channel is active, your console url changes to https protocol and admin port. By defaut, it is 9002. So your console url would be https://<host>:9002/console.
You cannont use anymore port 7001 for administration tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Easily you should change one property on config file

1. find *config.xml* file on *DOMAIN-HOME\config* directory
2. find this node and change the value to '*false*'

> `<administration-port-enabled>true</administration-port-enabled>`
>   
>   Enjoy browsing weblogic console!