# Disabling the admin port without using Weblogic console

Tags: oracle, eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c

I enabled the 'admin port' in the WebLogic Admin Console and now can't get back into the console to change it since I can't start the server.

When I try to start the server, I get this message in Eclipse:

> [Stopped, User'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has administration role. All tasks by administrator administrators must go through an Administration Port.

When trying to access the console via browser, I get this message:

> Console/Management requests or requests with  specified to 'true' can >only be made through an administration channel.

This [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656635/how-to-disable-admin-port-in-weblogic-without-weblogic-console/21660361#21660361?newreg=edc5fb9d3af64345b4b115c9eb3966d6) to this problem suggested modifying the `<administration-port-enabled>` element in the DOMAIN-HOME\config directory, but this element does not exist in my config.xml. Should I add it?

I have tried creating a new workspace and a new domain, but the problem persists.

Is there another way to disable the 'admin port' without using the WebLogic Admin Console or editing the config.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin
./wlst.sh
connect()
And Navigate to AdminServer and find the required Mbean

If not possible to connect, try with Offline Mode.